# boxplot of request latency versus time of request

Tags: r

I have a dataset that captures the latency of a number of network requests from multiple clients to a server:

```
              request_timestamp latency
1  2014-12-08T12:22:53.344+0000       9
2  2014-12-08T12:22:53.328+0000       2
3  2014-12-08T12:23:54.254+0000       7
...
10 2014-12-08T12:24:12.749+0000       6
```

I would like to be able to perform a box plot where the x axis is the time in minutes, e.g.

```
20141208T1222 20141208T1223 20141208T1224 ...
```

And the boxes would summarize the data within the corresponding minute.

I believe I need a function similar to this:

```
tmp <- boxplot(latency ~ request_timestamp_minute, data=DF, plot=FALSE) 
bxp(tmp, at=sort(unique(df$request_timestamp_minute)))
```

I would also like to aggregate by different timestamp values, such as hour, quarter of hour, etc.

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for hours, minutes, day, etc:

```
library("lubridate")

# make more margin space for x axis label
par.old <- par(mar=c(10,4,4,2)) 

# add a new field containing the request timestamp as a POSIXct type
DF$req_time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(DF$request_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))

# add a new field to store the hour interval
DF$req_time_hour <- round_date(DF$req_time, "hour")

# now do the plotting
tmp <- boxplot(latency ~ req_time_hour, data=DF, plot=FALSE)
bxp(tmp, log = "y", las=2, at=sort(unique(DF$req_time_hour)))

# reset the margins
par(par.old)
```

This is a [link](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/2/10/using-times-and-dates-in-r---presentation-code.html) to the blog post that helped provide this solution.

I'll ask a separate question about rounding to other increments of time such as quarter of an hour.